# Difficulty when rendering objects using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following interface:

```
interface ExamData {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  essay_questions: boolean;
}
```

I refer to the table in the state below:

```
  const [exam, setExam] = useState<ExamData[]>([]);
```

When I try to render an item, I get the error:

```
<h6>{exam.title}</h6>

// Error
Property 'title' does not exist on type 'ExamData[]'.  TS2339
```

Comment: `useState<ExamData[]>` the square brackets mean that it's an **array** of `ExamData` objects, not just one. So `exam` refers to an array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to render *many* exams, or a *single* exam?

Since you're using an array, you probably want many exams, in which case you should use something like:

```
{
  exam.map((item) => <h6>{item.title}</h6>)
}
```

I'd also highly recommend using precise variable names to avoid these sorts of issues - it's an array, not a single element, so maybe call it `exams` instead of `exam`:

```
const [exams, setExams] = useState<ExamData[]>([]);
```

```
{
  exams.map((exam) => <h6>{exam.title}</h6>)
}
```

Your original code isn't working because the `exam` variable refers to an *array*, not something of type `ExamData` - so it doesn't have a `title` property.

If you really wanted to have just a single exam in state, then change the state to

```
const [exam, setExam] = useState<ExamData>();
```

and then do

```
<h6>{exam?.title}</h6>
```

Comment: It is a single exam.

So to work, would it be just taking out the []?